# How to resize finder icons in 10.7 Lion

Tags: macos

How do I resize icons in Lion's finder. So for example if I wanted to resize the icons in the application folder. In Snow leopard, there used to be a slider at the bottom of the finder page, but thats gone in Lion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the menu bar click View -> Show Status Bar

[image]

The status bar will appear at the bottom of the Finder window with the icon size slider on the right hand side.

[image]